# Intersection of a Cartier and Weil divisor on a normal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal, projective algebraic variety. I have a (bad) Weil divisor $D$ and a Cartier divisor $C$. Can it happen that they meet, but in codimension greater than $2$? If yes, does this imply, that their intersection (as a class in $A_{k-2}$) is zero?

Comment: Apply Krull's Hauptidealsatz to $C\cap D$ inside $D$.

Comment: OK I see the equation of C cannot cut in D anything of bigger codim and normality has nothing to do with it! Thanks, and sorry for a stupid question.